# error when using the keras api on convelutional layers

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, theano

I'm trying to build a model that looks like this:

```
input
  /
convlayers/flatten
   /         \
first_output  \
     \        /
   second_output
```

but it fails at the first conv layers with the error:

```
ValueError: Layer conv2d_4 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor.
Received type: <class 'keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D'>.
Full input: [<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f450d7b8630>].
All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

and the error points to the layer after the first conv with the inputshape call.

Help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
conv1 = Conv2D(8, 4, padding = "same", strides = 2)(inputs)
conv2 = Conv2D(16 ,4, padding = "same", strides = 2)(conv1)
flat = Flatten()(conv2)
dense1 = Dense(32)(flat)

dense2 = Dense(32)(dense1)
first_output = Dense(64)(dense2)
merged = concatenate([flat,first_output])
second_output_dense1 = Dense(32)(merged)
second_output_dense2 = Dense(32)(second_output_dense1)
second_output = Dense(64)(second_output_dense2)

model = Model(inputs=conv1, outputs=[first_output,second_output])
model.compile(loss = "mse", optimizer = "adam" )
```

Answer:

i was under the impression that you could call the model without an input layer and just define the input in the first layer : conv1 = Conv2D(8, 4, padding = "same", strides = 2, ***input_shape = (6,8,8,)***)

but that didnt work so instead you have to delete the input shape thing and create an input layer here is the fixed code

```
inputs = Input(shape=(6,8,8,))
conv1 = Conv2D(8, 4, padding = "same", strides = 2, input_shape = (6,8,8,))
conv2 = Conv2D(16 ,4, padding = "same", strides = 2)(conv1)
flat = Flatten()(conv2)
dense1 = Dense(32)(flat)

dense2 = Dense(32)(dense1)
first_output = Dense(64)(dense2)
merged = concatenate([flat,first_output])
second_output_dense1 = Dense(32)(merged)
second_output_dense2 = Dense(32)(second_output_dense1)
second_output = Dense(64)(second_output_dense2)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[first_output,second_output])
model.compile(loss = "mse", optimizer = "adam" )
```

Comment: You're not calling the first conv layer on anything.

Comment: what do i need to call it on?

Comment: ...the input? You might want to review the basics of the functional API in Keras... https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/